# How to define Outline direction in Excel Data Grouping

Tags: microsoft-excel-365

In Excel 365 (version 1908), I want to group columns using the Data -> Outline -> Group function. This works fine, but it only groups columns to the right. However, I want to group the columns to the left. In Excel 2013, I could define the grouping behavior by clicking on the little arrow on the bottom right side of the Outline section in the ribbon. In Excel 365, this icon is greyed out. How can I enable this feature?

This basically also applies to grouping rows to top vs. bottom.

[image]

Comment: What version exactly do you consider the "previous version" considering is not the current version?  Please edit your question instead of replying with a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to make sure your cursor is not inside a table. I had the same issue. Click on a blank cell outside the table and it will work.